# Why Keyof makes object undefined and impossible to make a proper check

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined' when I try to find an object's value by dynamically selecting the key. For some reason, typescript doesn't allow me to check the values of the field and I'm not sure what the reason is. Check the code below, please!

```
import {calculateAge} from "../helpers/ageCalculator";

export class EmployeeModel {
    id: number;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    birthdate: string;
    email: string;
    gender: string;
    department: string;
    age?: number = 0;

    constructor(employee: EmployeeModel = {} as EmployeeModel) {
        this.id = employee.id;
        this.first_name = employee.first_name;
        this.last_name = employee.last_name;
        this.birthdate = employee.birthdate;
        this.email = employee.email;
        this.gender = employee.gender;
        this.department = employee.department;
        this.age = calculateAge(employee.birthdate);
    }
```

```
    export const useGetEmployees = () => {
    const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

    const sortBy = searchParams.get('sortBy');
    const direction = searchParams.get('direction');

    const compareFunc = (a:EmployeeModel, b: EmployeeModel) => {
        let sortResult = 0;

        if (a === undefined && b === undefined) {
            return 0;
        }

        //TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
        if (a[sortBy as keyof EmployeeModel] < b[sortBy as keyof EmployeeModel]){
            sortResult = -1;
        }

        //TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
        if ( a[sortBy as keyof EmployeeModel] > b[sortBy as keyof EmployeeModel] ){
            sortResult = 1;
        }

        else return sortResult;
        return  direction === SortDirection.Desc ? -sortResult : sortResult;
    };

    const { data, isLoading, status } = useQuery('employeeList', getEmployeeList, {
        select: (employees: EmployeeModel[]) => employees.map(
            (employee: EmployeeModel) => {
                return new EmployeeModel(employee);
            }
        ).sort(compareFunc),
    });
    return {employees: data, isLoading, status} as const;
}
```

```
export const calculateAge = (birthdate: string) : number => {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();

    const birthDate = new Date(birthdate);
    const birthYear = birthDate.getFullYear();

    return currentYear - birthYear;
}
```

UPD: Added calculateAge() code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem comes from `age?`. It could be undefined and as such any access to a `EmployeeModel` via a key string could be undefined.

You have a few options here:

1. define `age` as `number`: `age: number`, but I don't know how `calculateAge` looks like.
2. get the values from `a[key]` and `b[key]` and check them for undefined.
3. exclude `age` from the list of keys.

```
const key: Exclude<keyof EmployeeModel, "age"> = sortBy as Exclude<keyof EmployeeModel, "age">
    
if (key) {
   if (a[key] < b[key]){
      sortResult = -1;
   }

   if ( a[key] > b[key] ){
       sortResult = 1;
   }
}
```

A few notes:

- this check `if (a === undefined && b === undefined)` is not needed.
- I would create a key value at the top and reuse it. Something like this

```
        const key: = sortBy as keyof EmployeeModel
    
        if (key) {
            if (a[key] < b[key]){
                sortResult = -1;
            }

            if ( a[key] > b[key] ){
                sortResult = 1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for you comment, added calculate age to the question

Comment: Then you just need to change to age: number = 0, without the optional